# Bootstrap behaves inappropriate in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have an application that I am switching to bootstrap. All of the design works in development, but once deployed in precompiled production, the design is "messed up" for lack of a better term.

For some reason, everything in the page is truncated to a smaller, centered portion of the page and there is a large margin between the top of the page and the navbar (which should be a fixed navbar)

Does anyone have any insight as to what I may be doing wrong with deployment? I am using the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem and all of the standard 3.1 asset pipeline gems.

Comment: Can the browser fetch all resources or do you get some errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to properly update the gem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're doing your templates, but ideally you should do a diff comparison between your source and compiled code. In any case, my bet is that there is a grid `<div class="row">` or `<div class="span*">` out of place somewhere. Grid issues fit what you're describing perfectly. By the way, are you using `.row` with `.container`? or `.row-fluid` with `.container-fluid`. Both are solid when implemented correctly, but the fluid grid seems to be easier to break. Just a thought.

Comment: I have since figured it out. It was just a gem that hadn't been properly updated.

Comment: it would be good to either mark the answer as accepted or put how you solved it yourself, since other people may need an answer to the same question.